# I keep getting these errors and they're not going away. I'm a newbie and this is an easy code

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a chess game for my uni project. Up until now, I have only studied `if`/`else`, `for`/`while`/`goto`, 1D/2D arrays, pointers, and functions. I can only use these things in my code.

I have written a code and the problem that occurs is here:

When I'm taking input from user as rank-rank addresses, I am trying to store them in an array. I tried using 8 variables for it, but after 3 moves the first ade move resets.

Also, I keep getting this error :

> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\FinalChess\Debug\FinalChess.exe 1   1   FinalChess

and

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl gameboard(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?gameboard@@YAHHHHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\FinalChess\FinalChess\Source.obj    FinalChess

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int BL = 19;
string boardBorder[BL][BL];
//string *rankFile[8][8];
string swapper;
char sp = ' ';

int gameboard( int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);

void pieceplace()
{
    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
        {
            if (ROW == 4 && COL>0 && COL<18 && COL % 2 == 0)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'S';
            if (ROW == 14 && COL>0 && COL < 18 && COL % 2 == 0)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 's';
            if (ROW == 2 && COL == 2 || ROW == 2 && COL == 16)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'R';
            if (ROW == 16 && COL == 2 || ROW == 16 && COL == 16)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'r';
            if (ROW == 2 && COL == 4 || ROW == 2 && COL == 14)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'H';
            if (ROW == 16 && COL == 14 || ROW == 16 && COL == 4)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'h';
            if (ROW == 2 && COL == 6 || ROW == 2 && COL == 12)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'B';
            if (ROW == 16 && COL == 12 || ROW == 16 && COL == 6)
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = 'b';
            boardBorder[2][10] = 'K';
            boardBorder[16][10] = 'k';
            boardBorder[2][8] = 'Q';
            boardBorder[16][8] = 'q';
        }
    }
}

int moves = 1;

void main()
{
    int from[197], from2[197], to[197], to2[197], f[197], f2[197], t[197], t2[197];
    pieceplace();
    gameboard(from[197], from2[197], to[197], to2[197], f[197], f2[197], t[197], t2[197]);
    pieceplace();
    /*for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
    {
    rankFile[i][j] = &boardBorder[i * 2][j * 2];
    }
    }*/
    for (; moves <= 1972; moves++)
    {
        cout << "\t\tPlayer white's turn : ";
        cout << "Please enter current rank-to-rank address : ";
        cin >> from[moves] >> from2[moves];
        cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease enter a new rank-to-rank address : ";
        cin >> to[moves] >> to2[moves];

        boardBorder[to[moves] * 2][to2[moves] * 2] = boardBorder[from[moves] * 2][from2[moves] * 2];
        boardBorder[from[moves] * 2][from2[moves] * 2] = " ";

        system("CLS");
        gameboard(from[197], from2[197], to[197], to2[197], f[197], f2[197], t[197], t2[197]);

        moves++;

        cout << "\t\tPlayer black's turn : ";
        cout << "Please enter current rank-to-rank address : ";
        cin >> f[moves] >> f2[moves];
        cout << "\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease enter a new rank-to-rank address : ";
        cin >> t[moves] >> t2[moves];

        boardBorder[t[moves] * 2][t2[moves] * 2] = boardBorder[f[moves] * 2][f2[moves] * 2];
        boardBorder[f[moves] * 2][f2[moves] * 2] = " ";

        system("CLS");
        gameboard(from[197], from2[197], to[197], to2[197], f[197], f2[197], t[197], t2[197]);
    }

    cout << "\n\n\n";
}

int gameboard(int from[197], int from2[197], int to[197], int to2[197], int f[197], int f2[197], int t[197], int t2[197])
{
    system("color F0");

    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
        {
            if (ROW >= 1 && ROW <= 17 && COL == 1 || ROW >= 1 && ROW <= 17 && COL == 17)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "|";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 == 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 != 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "|";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 != 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 != 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "+";
            }
            else if (ROW >= 1 && ROW % 2 != 0 && COL >= 2 && COL % 2 == 0 && ROW <= 17 && COL <= 16)
            {
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = "-";
            }
            else
                boardBorder[ROW][COL] = " ";
        }
    }
    int siders = 1, side = 1, upper = 1, up = 1;
    int mov = 1;

    pieceplace();

    boardBorder[to[mov] * 2][to2[mov] * 2] = boardBorder[from[mov] * 2][from2[mov] * 2];
    boardBorder[from[mov] * 2][from2[mov] * 2] = " ";
    mov++;
    boardBorder[t[mov] * 2][t2[mov] * 2] = boardBorder[f[mov] * 2][f2[mov] * 2];
    boardBorder[from[mov] * 2][from2[mov] * 2] = " ";

    for (int ROW = 0; ROW < BL; ROW++)
    {
        for (int COL = 0; COL < BL; COL++)
        {
            if (ROW == 0 && COL == 1 || ROW == 18 && COL == 1)
            {
                cout << "  ";
            }
            if (ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && ROW % 2 == 0 && COL == 1)
            {
                cout << siders++;
            }
            if (ROW >= 2 && ROW <= 16 && ROW % 2 == 0 && COL == 18)
            {
                cout << side++;
            }
            if (ROW == 0 && COL >= 2 && COL <= 18 && COL % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (upper < 9)
                    cout << "\b" << upper++;
            }
            if (ROW == 18 && COL >= 2 && COL <= 18 && COL % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (up < 9)
                    cout << "\b" << up++;
            }
            if (COL == 0)
                cout << endl;



            if (COL == 1 && ROW >= 1 && ROW <= 17 && ROW % 2 == 0)
            {
                cout << boardBorder[ROW][COL];
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " " << boardBorder[ROW][COL];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\bBoth Players must use the rank-to-rank address to choose or move a piece.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. I have removed the `C` tag.

Comment: Those are link errors which means the final executable will not have been produced. So it is not clear how you could have run the program to get  this result: "I tried using 8 variables for it but after 3 moves, the first ade move reset".

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a function that takes `int`s as parameters:

```cpp
int gameboard( int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

You've defined a 2nd function that takes *arrays* of `int`s:

```cpp
int gameboard(int from[197], int from2[197], int to[197], int to2[197], int f[197], int f2[197], int t[197], int t2[197])
```

In `main` you are attempting to call the function that takes `int`s

```cpp
gameboard(from[197], from2[197], to[197], to2[197], f[197], f2[197], t[197], t2[197]);
```

(The numbers in the square brackets are subscripts, not sizes.)

You have not actually defined the version of the function that takes `int` arguments and your attempt to call it results in linker errors.

Also, you are accessing elements of the arrays outside of their valid ranges. For example, `from[197]` references the 198th element of a 197-element array.